# Imacro using eval to remove two certain words

Tags: text, replace, eval

this is my code:

```js
TAG POS=82 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=85 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=86 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
'clean the extracted data:
SET replies EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\$|'[EXTRACT]'|#EANF#]/g, '');")
'below code is suppose to put the extracted replies into the summerizer box 
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://www.summarizing.biz/best-summarizing-strategies/article-summarizer-online/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:summarizingform ATTR=ID:draft CONTENT={{replies}}
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(1140,899)"
PROMPT "Please enter the captcha:" !VAR1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:summarizingform ATTR=ID:sum_secure CONTENT={{!var1}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:summar_btn
'Prompt and ask for the rephrased summery
PROMPT "type the rephhrased summery" !VAR2
TAB T=1
```

I'm trying to remove "[EXTRACT]" and "#EANF#" from the extracted data but when I use this code:

```
SET replies EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\$|'[EXTRACT]'|#EANF#]/g, '');")
```

it removes all capital "E X T R A C T" from the text. for example if I have the word "Report" in my extracted data it becomes "eport" after going through the Eval.

please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best, but a solution,
 1. Try to set the complete text as a var, f.ex:

```
SET !VAR1 and here goes your EXTRACTED TEXTS ETC.
```

2. Paste the text somewhere into an online notepad in a second tab, ghostbin, piratepad, ...

3. Record with experimental mode how you edit the text WITH the keyboard.
4. Set the edited text again as your new !VAR1 and use !VAR1 as your whole text

As said, not best solution etc. but could be one.

One question i still have, why dont you simply delete the words "[EXTRACT]" and "#EANF#" ?

Comment: Thanks man, even though I figured the Eval command out I appreiciate your solution....kinda interesting.

Answer (score 2):

here's the right eval command in case someone is interested:

`SET replies EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/(EXTRACT|#EANF#)/g, '');")`

oh my god this Eval thing is so powerful...opens a whole alot of possibilities for you...